# Ansible errors while using the with_sequence loop

Tags: ansible

i am testing looping code on ansible my first try worked:

```
  - file:
  state: touch
  path: /tmp/{{ item }}
with_sequence: start=0 end={{ find_result.examined }}
```

[this works the directorys are created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOshB.png)

but if i use the same loop to create users i get an error

```
 - name: User Creation
user:
  name: "{{ find_result.files[item].path | regex_replace('/root/00staging/sshkeys/') | regex_replace('_id_rsa.pub')}}"
  comment: nameduser
  password: "{{ 'Start123' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
  update_password: on_create
  createhome: true
  group: wheel
register: users_added
with_sequence: start=0 end={{ find_result.examined }}
```

The error:

`{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute u'0'\n\n`

it works when i use the loop `with_items` but this is not dynamic enough

the variable is not empty it gets filled by this code:

```
  - name: finding files
find:
  paths:            "/root/00staging/sshkeys"
  file_type:        "file"
register: find_result
```

Update:

i have the same error with simple sequence numbers the [item] is not getting filled but the {{ item }} gets filled correctly

**find_result.files[item].path**

**with_sequence: start=0 end=1**

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing:

```
'list object' has no attribute u'0'
```

Suggests that the value of the `find_result.files` key is an empty list.  In the first iteration of your loop you're trying to access `find_result.files[0]`, but if that list is empty there is no element 0. You can generate the same error with the following example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    empty_list: []
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "item {{ item }} is {{ empty_list[item] }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end=1
```

You should inspect the contents of the `find_result` variable (using e.g. a `debug` task) to confirm that it contains what you think it should contain.